# Dynamic routing for static sites?

Tags: next.js

I'm tying to add projects I have made to my portfolio site using Airtable as a simple data base.

I have successfully fetched and displayed the projects and routed to each projects ID. However I am stuck on how to get the other data from that specific project and to display it. Statically.

Getting the data from Airtable functionality:

```
export async function getProjectsData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.airtable.com/v0/${BASE_KEY}/Projects?api_key=${API_KEY}`
  );
  const airtable = await res.json();

  const projectData = await airtable.records
    .map(record => {
      return {
        name: record.fields.Name,
        notes: record.fields.Notes,
        siteURL: record.fields.SiteURL,
        codeURL: record.fields.CodeURL,
        screenshots: record.fields.Screenshots.map(img => img.url),
        tech: record.fields.Tech,
        id: record.fields.ID,
      };
    })
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.id < b.id) {
        return -1;
      } else return 1;
    });
  return projectData;
}
```

Displaying the name of each project on homepage using getStaticProps()

```
          <ul>
            {projects.map((project, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <h3>{project.name}</h3>
                <Link href='/projects/[id]' as={`/projects/${project.id}`}>
                  <a>Find out more</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const projects = await getProjectsData();

  return {
    props: {
      projects,
    },
  };
}
```

Using `[id].js` for a dynamic routing when clicking Link above for each project sent to this page but with dynamic slug.

```
export default function Project() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is a project</h1>
      <Link href='/'>
        <a>Home</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My problem is that I want the rest of my project data to be displayed on the Project page using dynamic routing and SSG. I have read the docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get `[id].js` to work? Have you added `getStaticProps` to `[id].js` to query Airtable using the project Id which is `context.params.id`? (`context` is the parameter of `getStaticProps`)  [getStaticProps (Static Generation)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)

Comment: Similarly to the above comment: [id].js inside pages/ should just be used for data fetching and I would store my Project page template in components/. Within [id].js you would have a getStaticProps where you would read from the params the ID of the project. Then you can create a similar function to getProjects that fetches the projectData using the project id